# Display image from model to template Django

Tags: django, image, templates

The image can upload to the file "upload" which located in mysite file, here is my code
 setting.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/Python26/mysite/upload/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

In the url.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

   url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,}),
)
```

In the template

```
 <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/{{pic}}" alt="Profile Picture" width="200"/>
```

However, the image still does not show in the website, but it indeed stored in the upload file. Someone could help me with that? Thanks

Comment: when your html renders what is the value of `src`?

Comment: it is <img src="/upload/Desert.jpg" alt="Profile Picture" width="200"/><br/>

Comment: which is the right location of the image

Comment: `/upload/Desert.jpg` isn't right, Perhaps it should be `/media/Desert.jpg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

And the following template code:

```
<img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/{{pic}}" alt="Profile Picture" width="200"/>
```

The image `src` couldn't possibly be `/upload/Desert.jpg`. The path should be starting with `/media/`. More likely than not `MEDIA_URL` is undefined and the value of `pic` is `upload/Desert.jpg`. If that's the case, then you're probably missing the media template context processor. Change `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` to:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
)
```

That will make `MEDIA_URL` available in your template context. Then, you'll also need to remove the slash after it, or you'll end up with two (`MEDIA_URL` ends with a slash), i.e.:

Instead of:

```
{{ MEDIA_URL }}/{{ pic }}
```

Use:

```
{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ pic }}
```

**UPDATE**

If you're *still* not getting a value for `MEDIA_URL`, then you're probably not using `RequestContext`. You have to wrap your view's context in `RequestContext` in order for the template context processors to do their thing.

If you're using `render_to_response`, then:

```
return render_to_response('template.html', { ... context here ... }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

If you're using Django 1.3+, you can just use the `render` method, which will do this for you automatically:

```
return render('template.html', { ... context here ... })
```

Comment: I did that, but it came out <img src="upload/Desert.jpg" alt="Profile Picture" width="200"/><br/>

Comment: Thanks:) I think the {{ MEDIA_URL }} is upload/, I am wondering is there any problem with MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/Python26/mysite/upload/media/', but I can not figure out

Comment: Looks like `MEDIA_URL` is still undefined. The only other possible issue is that you're not using `RequestContext`. See update above.

Comment: I am using Django1.4, and I changed my code to render('template.html', { ... context here ... })

Comment: Add `{% debug %}` to your template and inspect the template context (easier if you view source on the page). If `MEDIA_URL` isn't in there (which is surely won't be) and you're using `render`, then it goes back to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`. Make sure it's actually what you think it is. You might want to try `python manage.py shell` and then running from there `from django.conf import settings` and `settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` to see what it's truly set to.

Comment: thanks a lot, now I can get the MEDIA_URL like this <img src="/media/upload/Desert.jpg" alt="Profile Picture" width="200"/><br/>
but still no pic shows...

Comment: Do I need to import settings to view.py or url.py something?

Comment: No, settings is the first thing that loads just to start Django. Based on your `MEDIA_ROOT`, I doubt the value for `pic` is correct. Would it really be in a folder at `C:/Python26/mysite/upload/media/upload/`?

Comment: Ok, I finally figured out, just like you said, I put context_instance=RequestContext(request) into my view.py. Thank you very much, very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

In settings, this didn't work for me,

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
)
```

Instead of `django.core....` I used `django.template....`

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    'django.template.context_processors.media',
)
```